# How to read an image stored in Android application's folder in Internal Shared Storage using html?

Tags: android, html, xml, xslt

My app is saving camera photos into `Internal shared storage\my app\photos`

It is also saving a XML file and one of the pieces inside that file is the name of the photo file.

I'm using XSLT to transform the XML into HTML for printing purposes.

I can successfully render an image from `src\main\res\drawable` using HTML in my WebView by using

`<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/image.png"/>`

How can I render the image in Internal shared storage?

Comment: I do not know where you refer to talking about internal shared storage but it is with file://<path to file>.

Comment: Thank you - and how does the path start? E.g. is it literally `file://Internal shared storage/my app/photos`?

I thought Internal Shared Storage was standard for Android?

Comment: I tried `<img src=file://Internal%20shared%20storage/myphoto.jpg/>` but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got to it with

```
<img src="file:///storage/emulated/0/myapp/photos/myphoto.jpg"/>
```